# Encrypt PHP string and decrypt after page reload

Tags: php, encryption

I am creating a sign up page, when you attempt to sign up it will generate a random six digit number. This number will then be emailed to you, where you then enter that number in the browser to 'verify'.

Although I am having trouble with encrypting the string and then decrypting it after the page has reloaded, I was passing the key and iv_size via a form which not only doesn't actually work, I would also presume it to be wildy unsafe as the IV is supposed to be kept secret.

So here is the question, how do I encrypt a string in PHP and decrypt it after the page has reloaded, essentially a new page as no variables remain.

Giving you my current code is kinda silly because it isn't working, but here it is incase you think you can fix it;

```
$randInt = mt_rand(0, 9);
            for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
                $randInt .= mt_rand(0, 9);
            }
            $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
            $key_size =  strlen($key);
            $plaintext = $randInt;
            $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
            $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
            $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
            $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
            $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

            ?>
            <script>
                notify('Please Enter The Verification Number We Sent You Below', "#C60");
            </script>
            <?
            echo('We sent a verification code to the email provided, please enter it below to continue with your sign up process.');

            ?>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="encryptedKey" value="<?php echo($ciphertext_base64);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="ivSize" value="<?php echo($iv_size);?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo($key);?>">
                <input type="number" name="verify" id="verify">
            </form>
```

and this is that part that is supposed to decrypt it:

```
$iv_size = $_POST['ivSize'];
            $key = $_POST['key'];
            $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($_POST['encryptedKey']);
            $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
            $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);
            $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);
            echo  $plaintext_dec . "\n";
```

Even if this can be fixed, it is still too insecure. The error I am getting is telling me the key it too long, if I put the two code blocks together, it works, but when I separate them, they do not work. I feel like the form is messing up the variables when passing.

Comment: You can use Sessions to store the data instead of encoding it. What happens when the user clicks the link in the email and another browser opens? You should prefer a database solution.

Comment: For many encryption algorithms, the IV does not need to be secret (just be unique usually) while the key should be. Also, it looks like you are trying to use a 256-bit key for Rijndael/AES-128. As the name says, AES-128 has a key size of 128 bits = 16 bytes (your key is 32 bytes = 64 hex-string chars).

Comment: If the key is the incorrect size, then why does it work if I put the code blocks one after another, is there away of using Ajax to submit the form without reloading the page, therefore removing the need to encrypt?

Comment: Wouldn't using the session method be insecure because they can see the code that needs to be entered, it also wouldn't keep the key secret either.

Comment: @Archimedix AES (Rijndael-128) has a fixed blocksize of 128-bit, but can use key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit. The 128 in AES-128 means the keysize, but the 128 in Rijndael-128 means the blocksize.

Comment: @ArtjomB. So `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is not the key, but the block size? That's interesting... thought it were the former because there are also `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192` and `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` which coincide with AES key sizes (while block sizes are always 128). It isn't entirely clear because it refers to an entire _cipher_.

Comment: Anyways, @Harry, it looks like you don't need encryption, just store the validation code in a database (or in `$_SESSION`, see [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/function.session-start.php)) along with the e-mail address and then look that up when the user visits your site via the validation link or enters the code. If the code / e-mail address pair exists, consider the address validated. Using AJAX is not needed - you can load a whole new page when the code is entered (and compare the code against the value from the database or from `$_SESSION`).

Comment: @Archimedix The key size is automatically determined by how many bytes are passed in as the key. And the special case for PHP is that if there are not enough bytes for a specific key size, the key is filled up with 0x00 to the next valid size.

Comment: @Archimedix so your saying to create the account but set it disabled, then another page where they enter the number that would also be stored in the database, I'm thinking maybe it would be better to not create the account until it's entered to save database entries. All I really need is to be able to get the input from the form into pho without reloading. Storing the number in the session is insecure because you can view that using your browser.

Comment: @Harry I didn't say you should create the _account_ but that you could store e-mail & code in a "validation" record so you can retrieve it later. That's what most sites do, and allows for asynchronicity - e-mails may be delayed for hours; the user may have closed the first page, so AJAX wouldn't work. And you have a false notion of a _session_. The browser only stores a cookie with the session _ID_ (or has the ID in the URL) to retrieve the session data on the _server_. So unless you _expose_ the data, the user _cannot_ see any of that but can just be _linked_ to them via the session _ID_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for the question he made in the comment area in my previous answer . **[IS NOT THE ANSWER TO HIS ORIGINAL QUESTION]**

Html File

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="validation-form">
<input id="validation-key" name="validation-key">
</form>

 <script>
      $('#validation-form').submit(function(){
            var data = $('#validation-form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:"validation_key.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:data,
                success:function(result){
                    // do what when the form validation is success
                    alert(result);

                },
                error:function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }
            })
      })
</script>
```

PHP Validation file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['validation-key'])) {
    // DO what you to validate the key is in here

    if($_POST['validation-key'] == "123456"){
        echo "Valid key";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid key";
    }


}else{
    echo "Validation key is missing";
}
```

Don't forget to add jquery lib 
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js

Comment: Nevermind, I was being dumb and said this wouldn't work, I stand corrected.

Comment: Because this requires JavaScript, I may avoid it as with it off the signup page wouldn't work, I will probably go for the option of creating the user straight away but settings it to disabled, then a link with a unique hash will be sent to the email, once clicked the account will become active

Answer (score 1):

If you are encoding and decoding integers I recommend you to look into Hashids Lib 
http://hashids.org/php/.

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids();
$id = $hashids->encode(1, 2, 3);
// Output $id => laHquq
```

You can use array of numbers or a single number and limit the chars in encoding level .

Read Hashids document you will understand

Comment: Is there a way to use Ajax to submit the mini form without reloading the page, therefore removing the need for encryption, I haven't used Ajax, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: if you could explain whats "mini form" I might be able to help

Comment: In the php ile there is a form  where you enter your sign up details, but the text input for the verification code is what I referred to as the mini form, this is the form posted above.

Comment: let me get right . you want to create a sign-up form with a email validation . but your not clear how can you do that I guess.

Comment: Go trough the following link to learn how todo Sign-up and email validation http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-email-verification-for-new-members--net-3824

Comment: I know how to do the form, it works fine, i have a second form that asks you to enter the 6 didgit number, I need to get the value of that text box into PHP without reloading the page

Comment: i'll add the solution as a another answer